# Rigging cartoon mouth

Tags: rigging, armature

So I have no idea how to rig the mouth on this character (the small black stripe between the eyes in the picture).
I only need to be able to make the corners go up so he can smile but i have no idea how to do it!

I tried using the armature but when I connect the bones to the mouth it doesn't work

[image: Character picture]

Comment: if you want a very basic way to animate maybe look for shapekeys, for more complex animation, you'll have to use bones

Comment: I suspect the mouth only has 8 vertices and then it won't work. If so, make sure it is subdivided so it looks more like a bunch of cubes in a row. (In Edit Mode pressing `Ctrl + R` and turning the mouse wheel will give you loopcut subdivisions.)

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! I managed to get it to work with the shapekeys!